# Is there a way to modularize cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Right now I am using a template in such a way:

1. Create initial resources
2. Import existing resources (S3)
3. Update stack with new resources depending on existing resources

This is boring because I have to deploy the stack in a 3-step process, commenting out depending on resources.

I've read about cloudformation modules but they don't seem to solve the problem with merging  3-step process (init, import existing, use existing) into single cloudformation template.

Is there a solution for such a case?

UPD: I do understand that I can just use resource ARN to reference existing resources without importing them but it doesn't solve the case where I need to attach additional things to my resources (here I create event notification to imported S3 bucket):

```
# Import existing resource
S3DataBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
```

```
# Modify template by adding event configuration
S3DataBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      NotificationConfiguration:
        LambdaConfigurations:
          - Event: s3:ObjectCreated:Put
            Filter:
              S3Key:
                Rules:
                  - Name: prefix
                    Value: !Ref SomePrefix
            Function: !GetAtt SomeLambda.Arn
```

Comment: Would parameters + condition functions work? Use these to switch resources on and off. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html

Comment: @Shane parameters won't help, cloudformation does not allow you to embed existing resources with other ones. Furthermore, you have to additionally modify template and deploy it again to have new parameters set, because the parameters set before are immutable. Also some changes should be done to previosly created resources that depends on existing one. (for example, use imported bucket arn in policy)

Comment: To be honest, despite deploying cloudformation templates every day I do not understand what you are exactly doing. Why you create resources outside of the CF and then import them back into it? Or what you do import where? I do complex deployments by embedding them in higher level automation (a simple example - write a script which does your 3 steps and call that script instead of doing your manual steps). I do not understand what is preventing you from doing the same. Also, I do modify parameters and template resources and cloudformation does take care of my update. What do I miss?

Comment: @petrch I have an existing resource bucket that should not be recreated so I import it in a template to give my lambdas exact permissions for accessing this bucket. I wonder if there is any way to do it without coding these steps in the script. The problem with script is that have to have 3 separate templates or code some parsesr that will dynamically append new sections to the base template.

Comment: What is the benefit of having the resources in step 2 in the CF template?
You do not need to import them in order to use them in step 3. You can just reference them by id or ARN.

Comment: @Shane by importing resource in stack I can attach resource-specific parameters (for example, I attach S3 event notification, you cannot do that unless you explicitly import the resource) (I edited question for illustrate this)

Comment: @VladyslavChaikovskyi do you maybe looking for exporting output variables? you can import the s3 bucket once in a separate template and then export the output from that template. After that, you can refer to the values from any CF template. But I think that for one 3 bucket any approach is good. You can also consider to use something like ssm parameters for sharing some of your values - maybe not directly applicable here, it's more like a side-note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is an issue open for this, but AWS aren't too interested in fixing it: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/79

In the mean time, you could consider a few of things:

1. AWS have suggested a workaround using eventbridge: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig-eventbridgeconfig.html#cfn-s3-bucket-eventbridgeconfiguration-eventbridgeenabled
2. Does the notification really need to be in the CFN template? Could you just add it manually, the same way that the bucket was added?
3. Can you script the "boring work" using the AWS CLI and some JSON/YAML editors or AWS CDK?

Comment: Yop, eventbridge can fit this problem. After a quick search, I see that event bridge is a more flexible way to work with events. Here's the [medium](https://eoins.medium.com/comparing-two-ways-to-trigger-lambda-from-s3-b5da8cfe1aee) article for others to see the comparison of both approaches.